# How to get position slot allowance automatic

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, ethers.js, trace

how to get position slot allowance automatically without looking at the code?  because each positive slot allowance in several different tokens, some of the default position is 2 but there are 3 and even 4

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.